# Terraform - Deploy ECS Service onto EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-ecs

I want to deploy ECS service that runs containers on EC2 machine(s),

Some factoids about my project:

1. as I have learned, pre-paid pricing model allow me to save significant money , so
   running my containers on own-managed EC2 can save lot
2. Fargate launch type seems not be an option
3. in this example I use 1 MongoDB container, that is available in AWS public ECR gallery
4. I opened every port in my rout table, maybe not a good idea, it just for try...
5. What I need is to run only 1 service with 1 EC2 instance, no up-scaling, etc
6. 

Now, the outcome is that

1. the deployment status is "In Progress"
2. I don't see any running task
3. Under the service -> "Deployments and events" tab: **service worker was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. Reason: No Container Instances were found in your cluster. For more information, see the Troubleshooting section of the Amazon ECS Developer Guide.**

The very annoying is that this message doesn't tell me anything about the real problem.

Can anybody point me, what did I miss? What made I wrong?

Anything, that I have to supply to understand my situation?

Here is my Terraform sample

```
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block = "172.30.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "internet_gateway" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
}

resource "aws_subnet" "pub_subnet" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block = "172.30.1.0/24"
}

resource "aws_route_table" "public" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.internet_gateway.id
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "route_table_association" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.pub_subnet.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public.id
}

resource "aws_security_group" "ecs_sg" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  ingress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port   = 0
    protocol  = "-1"
    self      = true
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs_agent" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_agent" {
  name               = "ecs-agent"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_agent.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_agent" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_agent.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role"
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "ecs_agent" {
  name = "ecs-agent"
  role = aws_iam_role.ecs_agent.name
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "vpc_endpoints" {
  for_each = toset(["com.amazonaws.us-east-1.logs", "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ecr.dkr", "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ecr.api", "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3", "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ecs", "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ecs-agent", "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ecs-telemetry"])

  vpc_id             = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  vpc_endpoint_type  = "Interface"
  service_name       = each.key
  security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.ecs_sg.id]
}

resource "aws_launch_template" "engine" {
  name          = "alma"
  image_id      = "ami-05339d597592d45cf" # Amazon ECS-Optimized Amazon Linux 2 (AL2) x86_64 AMI
  instance_type = "t2.large"
  user_data     = base64encode("#!/bin/bash\necho ECS_CLUSTER=my-cluster >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config")

  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.ecs_sg.id]
  iam_instance_profile {
    name = aws_iam_instance_profile.ecs_agent.name
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "failure_analysis_ecs_asg" {
  name                = "asg"
  vpc_zone_identifier = [aws_subnet.pub_subnet.id]

  desired_capacity          = 1
  min_size                  = 1
  max_size                  = 10
  health_check_grace_period = 300
  health_check_type         = "EC2"

  launch_template {
    id = aws_launch_template.engine.id
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_capacity_provider" "provider" {
  name = "alma"
  auto_scaling_group_provider {
    auto_scaling_group_arn = aws_autoscaling_group.failure_analysis_ecs_asg.arn

    managed_scaling {
      status                    = "ENABLED"
      target_capacity           = 100
      minimum_scaling_step_size = 1
      maximum_scaling_step_size = 100
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster_capacity_providers" "providers" {
  cluster_name       = aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster.name
  capacity_providers = [aws_ecs_capacity_provider.provider.name]
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "ecs_cluster" {
  name = "my-cluster"
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_definition" {
  family = "worker"
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      essential   = true
      memory      = 512
      name        = "worker"
      cpu         = 1
      image       = "public.ecr.aws/docker/library/mongo:5.0.10-focal"
      environment = []
    }
  ])
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "worker" {
  name            = "worker"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.task_definition.arn
  desired_count   = 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup is quite confusing. You are created a public subnet, which does not work (no public IP addresses), and then you have network interfaces for what reason is unclear. Anyway, I modified your code to actually work with a correctly setup public subnet:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = ">= 4.0"      
    }
   } 
}

provider "aws" {
  profile = "acc2"
  #region = "ap-southeast-2"
  region = "us-east-1"
}


resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block = "172.30.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_support = true  
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "internet_gateway" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
}

resource "aws_subnet" "pub_subnet" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block = "172.30.1.0/24"
  
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
}

resource "aws_route_table" "public" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.internet_gateway.id
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "route_table_association" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.pub_subnet.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public.id
}

resource "aws_security_group" "ecs_sg" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  ingress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port   = 0
    protocol  = "-1"
    self      = true
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs_agent" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_agent" {
  name               = "ecs-agent"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_agent.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_agent" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_agent.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role"
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "ecs_agent" {
  name = "ecs-agent"
  role = aws_iam_role.ecs_agent.name
}


# "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3", 

# resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "vpc_endpoints" {
#   for_each = toset(["com.amazonaws.us-east-1.logs", "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ecr.dkr", "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ecr.api", "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ecs", "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ecs-agent", "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ecs-telemetry"])

#   vpc_id             = aws_vpc.vpc.id
#   vpc_endpoint_type  = "Interface"
#   service_name       = each.key
#   security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.ecs_sg.id]
  
#   private_dns_enabled = true   
# }

resource "aws_launch_template" "engine" {
  name          = "alma"
  image_id      = "ami-05339d597592d45cf" # Amazon ECS-Optimized Amazon Linux 2 (AL2) x86_64 AMI
  instance_type = "t2.large"
  user_data     = base64encode("#!/bin/bash\necho ECS_CLUSTER=my-cluster >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config")

  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.ecs_sg.id]
  iam_instance_profile {
    name = aws_iam_instance_profile.ecs_agent.name
  }
  
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "failure_analysis_ecs_asg" {
  name                = "asg"
  vpc_zone_identifier = [aws_subnet.pub_subnet.id]

  desired_capacity          = 1
  min_size                  = 1
  max_size                  = 10
  health_check_grace_period = 300
  health_check_type         = "EC2"

  launch_template {
    id = aws_launch_template.engine.id
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_capacity_provider" "provider" {
  name = "alma"
  auto_scaling_group_provider {
    auto_scaling_group_arn = aws_autoscaling_group.failure_analysis_ecs_asg.arn

    managed_scaling {
      status                    = "ENABLED"
      target_capacity           = 100
      minimum_scaling_step_size = 1
      maximum_scaling_step_size = 100
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster_capacity_providers" "providers" {
  cluster_name       = aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster.name
  capacity_providers = [aws_ecs_capacity_provider.provider.name]
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "ecs_cluster" {
  name = "my-cluster"
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_definition" {
  family = "worker"
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      essential   = true
      memory      = 512
      name        = "worker"
      cpu         = 1
      image       = "public.ecr.aws/docker/library/mongo:5.0.10-focal"
      environment = []
    }
  ])
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "worker" {
  name            = "worker"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.task_definition.arn
  desired_count   = 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems, that the task started successfully.
The confusing thing is that in that case, I have a public subnet (if I'm right) so anybody can access our core infrastructure, which is definitely not what we want.
So how can I secure this configuration (Sorry, but AWS networking and the rule of thumb: which should I choose when, like subnet, security group, ACL or routing is pretty confusing)

Comment: @Moravas You have to create private subnet, connect it to NAT gateway, setup route tables. I would suggest trying doing that, and if get stuck, making new question with new code.